# Adobe apps won't open. Getting an Error 16 message

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I cannot open any of my adobe applications after installing on a new computer.

It is a copy of CS6 Master collection with a legitimate license.

I've already tried reinstalling and following the instructions in a help article on Adobe's site ["Configuration error 16 when you start a Creative Cloud (CC) or Creative Suite (CS) application"](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/configuration-error-cs5.html).

Any ideas?

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried what the error tells you to do? contacting adobe technical support? http://helpx.adobe.com/contact.html?

Comment: I've done what the error/knowledgebase suggests to do (as I said in my question). The only option for contacting adobe from what I can tell is the forum (for a product not purchased in the last 90 days).